Can't reproduce old longtable layout
I'm using a CV template found here: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/academic-cv-template/xykxmjmkxxjm
As can be seen in the example image, the two columns are vertically aligned such that the titles and first line of the paragraphs align.
When I go to build this template in Overleaf though, the first line of the paragraph is placed above the position of the title!

How can I fix the template to get it looking like the original again, with the beginnings of the paragraphs properly aligned?

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing .... How did you compile? Did you use MiKTeX or TeXlive? Which version?

Sorry for not being clear, I just opened that template I linked in overleaf and compiled it without changing anything, and it comes out like the image I've attached.

You need \leavevmode before the \color (or use \textcolor) the fact that \color at the start of a p column might up alignment isn't specific to longtable and isn't new, it's been documented in a footnote n grfrguide since 1994 when the color package was introduced. However this specific case appears to have changed in texlive 2024. So as an alternative to adding the \leavevmode you can use the left sidebar in overleaf to use the project with texlive 2023.

\leavevmode\nohyphens{\color{OliveGreen}{Research interests}}
& Your favorite topic, another topic, another topic, another topic, another topic \\


2023, no \leavevmode


This did it, thank you.
